# How to make use of a function's return value as a property in Maven for deploying to the right IP address?

Tags: java, maven

**tl/dr: Use java stand-alone method results as a maven property value?**

I've got a working maven pom.xml that builds a MYPROJECT-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar and deploys and deploys it to an IoT device on my LAN (using maven/antrun/scp).  Yay.

The problem is that the IP address needs to be updated in the pom.xml whenever the device changes addresses.

This isn't horrible, but I'd like to have it work automatically for anyone else that runs the code on THEIR device.  So I wrote a small (Kotlin) method that gets the IP address of the device: `fun getBrickIPAddress(): String? { ... stuff with Datagram packets... }`

Great!  Now, how would I make use of that java method's return value in the maven deploy steps?  Can you do that sort of "run this method, get the result, put the result into a maven properties variable, continue..."

Or do I need to have some child XML property file that the app creates?

*(disclaimer - not skilled with Maven)*

Comment: The sounds like a job for Ansible, Chef, Puppet, or simply a shell script not the job of Maven...

Comment: Sure!  Let's say I get the value back from a shell script.  Can Maven call that script and set a property = the return value?